# How to use facebook mentions via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

How to use facebook page mentions via Graph API?

I'm admin of the page and admin of the app, trying to mention page with @ syntax on its feed.

POST 1111111111111/feed/

```
{
  message: "Hello @[1111111111111]"
}
```

In this way, mention just striped. I'm tried to use my personal token, app token, page token. I have rights to publish_page, manage_page.

I tried to use @pagename, @[pagename], @page-id, @[page-id] etc...

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you an admin of _both_ pages, the one you are posting to and the one you are trying to mention? You need to get this reviewed by Facebook before it is supposed to work outside of those limitations.

Comment: @04FS I'm trying to post mention of the page to same page feed. Yes, I'm admin of this page.

Comment: Hm, I can’t currently get this to work either - @1234 just shows up as text, and @[1234] simply gets removed, as you said. Can’t find anything current regarding this on https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/ either, so perhaps best if you file a new bug report yourself.

Comment: Thank you for help @04FS, I create a bug in FB bugtracker. Will update question, after receiving an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer from Facebook support, they told us app should be in `development` mode to test this feature:

> I have confirmed with the engineering team that the reason you cannot
>   use the Page Mentions is because your app is in Live mode, but it
>   hasn't been approved for that feature. The docs are a bit confusing, I
>   agree. According to the docs: "Usage of this feature is subject to
>   review. To test before review, use Pages you are an admin of (both to
>   make the API call, and to be used in a mention) and an app of which
>   you are a developer."
>
> What this means is that you can test the feature while in Development
>   mode, but once the app goes Live, the feature will not work. In Live
>   mode, only features/permissions that your app has been approved for
>   will work. You can still submit an app that is in Live mode for app
>   review. Please see the Submission Tips for App Review for Live Apps:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#submission-tips